# Align element to bottom of container that uses display: table

Tags: html, css, layout, vertical-alignment

I have 3 boxes which need to be the same height with varying content. I am using display: table to achieve this. I need to vertically align the button to the bottom of the container. The button width could also change. I was not able to successfully get vertical-align: bottom to work.

http://codepen.io/simply-simpy/pen/kBaHt

```
<div id="cta-3-col" class="cta-3-col">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="cta">
            <figure>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/" alt="">
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>CTA 1</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing </p>
                    </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <a href="#" class="btn " role="button">Follow<i></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="cta">
            <figure>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/" alt="">
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>CTA 2</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt magna aliqua sed do edunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
                    </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <a href="#" class="btn" role="button">Partner With Us<i></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="cta">
            <figure>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/" alt="">
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>CTA 3</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
                    </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <a href="#" class="btn" role="button">Learn<i></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.cta {
    background: #fff;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 270px;
    padding: 0 0 30px;
 }
.cta-3-col {
    background: gray;
    text-align: center;
    border-spacing: 10px;
   }
 .container {
    display: table;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
.btn {
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I think it would be much easier to add "position:relative;" to the container and then use "position:aboslute;" to your buttoms with a bottom px value

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez -- The buttons need to be centered, and have a variable width. So, I am not sure how well that would work in this instance.

Comment: For now I am using the position absolute method and jQuery to set the offset. If anyone has a better way (with CSS only) please let me know.

Comment: Can't you wrap <a href="#" class="btn" role="button">Partner<i></i></a> in a DIV and text-align center in addition to the position absolute to the relative table-cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to change/add some CSS properties to your existing classes without adding extra markup:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rFmxa

CSS:

```
.cta {
  background: #fff;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 270px;
  /*padding: 0 0 30px;*/
  padding: 0 0 4em;
  position: relative;
}

.cta-3-col {
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: table;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%); 
 -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateX(-50%); 
 -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

look modified code without complex transform-translate properties wich will work in all browsers including ols IE!

advantages over other methods: **efficient, fast, cross-browser, easy!**

Codepen [YourSolution](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CfDBk)

**Modified css**

---

```
 .cta {
        background: #fff;
        display: table-cell;
        width: 270px;
        padding: 0 0 30px;
        position:relative;
    }

    .cta-3-col {
        background: gray;
        text-align: center;
        border-spacing: 10px;
        .container {
            display: table;
            width: 1000px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    }

    p {
        margin:10px 0px 40px 0px;
    }

    a.btn {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0px;
        width: 64px;
        margin: auto;
        background: blue;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the buttons must be flexible width.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's an updated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zIiFC).**

The bulk of the change was adding a `position:relative;` modifier to the `.cta` class and then giving the following rules to the class `.btn`:

```
  position:absolute;
  bottom:5px;
  left:50%;
  -moz-transform:translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
```

That should take care of the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
.cta {
    background: #fff; 
    display: table-cell;
    width: 270px;
    padding: 0 0 40px;
    position:relative;
} 
.btn {
    background: blue;
    color: #fff; 
    padding: 10px; 
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%; 
    bottom:0; 
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%); 
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%); 
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%); 
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%); 
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add below additional css and it will display your html as you requested:

```
- .cta {position:relative;}
- .btn {position:absolute;left:45%;bottom:0px;}
```